# How to style <select> elements?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, select, drop-down-menu

How can I completely change the design of a `<select>` element? For example, this is how I want my dropdown to look:

[image: Screeshot]

Is there a way to do it with CSS? If not, jQuery?

Comment: The answer depends on the OS/browser/version; what are you targeting?

Comment: is there reason why you donot want to go with jquery? it can be done very easily if you use jquery..

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do not "use jQuery" to replace a select. For all the wonderful things jQuery does, the jQuery UI is generally a usability abomination. Use a real `<select>` element, style it as you will, and accept that some browsers have made a (righteous) choice to use standard OS-level widgets with sometimes limited style changes. Users using the iPhone, for example, will greatly thank you for not using a JavaScript-based DHTML "solution" just so things look pretty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS will only help you in certain browsers - for instance, Internet Explorer will ignore it for SELECTs completely

you can, however, still use an ordinary select on page without any CSS whatsoever and then use a jQuery plugin that **degrades gracefully** (so when people don't have JS enabled, they will still see that original select box)

one of such plugins is this **[great jQuery UI selectmenu from Filament Group](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select)**

however, as pointed out by *clonked* in comments - use at least **some browser sniffing** to check whether people are not accessing that menu from iPhone or similar devices, as they might have problems accessing that JS select box

if you're by any chance using PHP on the server side, here's a nice browser sniffing library for you: http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Answer (score 2):

You will have issues achieving consistent styling of a `<select>` element with CSS alone.  Your best bet is to use jquery.  Fortunately a very nice plugin has already been created:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: As noted in the comments on that page: _"Hmmm.. Shouldn’t the functionality of form elements be up to the browser? For example, this kills the select that appears on the iPhone (and soon the iPad) that is most suitable for that platform."_ I can't downvote you because you have answered the desire of the OP...but I must point out that what the OP is asking for is _harmful_.

Comment: I agree with you, this type of functionality is not something I particularly enjoy implementing either.  But sometimes project requirements outweigh the right way to do things :)  Ideally using the upcoming http://jquerymobile.com/ would help mitigate some of these concerns for mobile devices.  I would also argue that until browser vendors allow all html elements to be styled as desired with CSS people we be searching for alternative methods like the `selectmenu()` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There are several jQuery plugins that will help you accomplish this.

Here is a light-weight one: http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/

And here is a tutorial to build one from scratch with images: 
http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way. Where selectBg.png is 1px background image. It will give an output like following image:

[image: modified select element]

CSS Code:

```
select.onlyOne {
    background: url("./theme/default/images/selectBg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #747862;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px 4px 8px 0;
    width: 430px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<select class="onlyOne" name="somename">
   <option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
   <option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can able to design select tag using jquery coding, Check the coding below

```
(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
        $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$('#btn-up').bind('click', function() {
    $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
        var newPos = $('#select-to option').index(this) - 1;
        if (newPos > -1) {
            $('#select-to option').eq(newPos).before("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"' selected='selected'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
$('#btn-down').bind('click', function() {
    var countOptions = $('#select-to option').size();
    $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
        var newPos = $('#select-to option').index(this) + 1;
        if (newPos < countOptions) {
            $('#select-to option').eq(newPos).after("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"' selected='selected'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

});
and the html code is

```
</select>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
<select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
  <option value="5">Item 5</option>
  <option value="6">Item 6</option>
  <option value="7">Item 7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

it's impossible!

the style is simulated by other html tags and css!